# Percentage increase for Treatment/Control in a cohort education study

Tags: effect-size, difference-in-difference, percentage

I have some Baseline and Midline results in a treatment/control study. In trying to calculate effect size for the treatment group, I'm using a Cohen's d calculation which allows for the discount in the gains made by the control group in assessing the true gains made by the treatment group (and pooled variation):

$$
d = \frac{(\bar{x}_{TM} - \bar{x}_{TB}) - (\bar{x}_{CM} - \bar{x}_{CB})}{\sqrt{\frac{(n_{CB}-1)s^2_{CB} + (n_{CM}-1)s^2_{CM} + (n_{TB}-1)s^2_{TB} + (n_{TM}-1)s^2_{TM}}{n_{CB} + n_{CM} + n_{TB} + n_{TM} - 4}}}
$$
(where T = Treatment, C = Control, M = Midline, and B = Baseline)

I'm also interested in the percentage increase/decrease in means or proportions over time, but I'm a little uncertain what equation to use. I wrote some code many years ago that uses this formula, but I don't feel like it's true:

$$
\% change = \frac{(\bar{x}_{TM} - \bar{x}_{TB}) - (\bar{x}_{CM} - \bar{x}_{CB})}{\bar{x}_{CB}}
$$
But I don't think that's correct. It seem to me that the denominator should take into account all the control group data, and thus be:
$$
\% change = \frac{(\bar{x}_{TM} - \bar{x}_{TB}) - (\bar{x}_{CM} - \bar{x}_{CB})}{(\bar{x}_{CM} - \bar{x}_{CB})}
$$

However, that also doesn't seem right to me. I feel like there might be some assumptions that I'm ignoring as well, such as an implicit assumption that my means for the baseline, both treatment and control, are comparable. However, in this data, they most certainly are not.Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance here?